# How to reference controller action from hidden action? Correct path?

Tags: plugin-development

I have seen a number of different paths, but, it is a bit confusing to me. What should be in my value in the HIDDEN input action below?

I have a twig page at my root:

```
<form method="post" action="" accept-charset="UTF-8">
    <input type="hidden" name="action" value="psychEmail/pubRequest">

    <!-- ...-->

    <input class="btn submit" type="submit" value="{{ 'Submit'|t }}">
</form>
```

and then I have a plugin `PsychEmailPlugin.php` class file with 
`class PsychEmailPlugin extends BasePlugin`

and then I have a controllers subdirectory with a `PsychEmailController.php` file that contains an action:

```
class PsychEmailController extends BaseController
{
    public function actionPubRequest($emailAddress)
    {
        $email = new EmailModel();
        $email->fromEmail = $emailAddress;
        $email->toEmail = 'myemail@gmail.com';
        $email->subject = 'Publication Request';
        $email->body    = 'Your requested publication is attached.';

        craft()->email->sendEmail($email);
    }
}
```

Comment: After some reading I changed my controller to PsychEmail_PublicationController. php, but, I am still having issues with the path.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After my changes, this worked:

```
value="psychEmail/publication/pubRequest"
```